# Nest JS DTO and Entity Model JSON mismatch issue

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I have requirement to accept type custom JSON from front end and I’m trying to achieve this in NestJS but I’m unable to resolve.

My entity model

```
import { GraphQLJSONObject } from “graphql-type-json”

 export class User {
   @Field(()=> GraphQLJSONObject)
   @Column({name: meta_data, type: simple-json})
    metaData: object
 }
```

DTO class:

```
 export class CreateUserDto {
  @Field()
  readonly metaData: object;
 }
```

I’m keep getting error

```
 Error: undefined type error. Make sure you are providing an explicit type for the metaData of CreateUserDto class
```

I’m new to Nestjs and Graphql.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `graphql-type-json` was correct. The error happens because Nest.js can't infer the type of the CreateUserDto.metadata field, You need to use a similar annotation.

```
@Field(() => GraphQLJSONObject)
readonly metaData: object;
```

For reference, such error can happen when you use an @Args field too (say in your mutation)

```
@Mutation((returns) => MyResultSchema)
async createUser(@Args('user', { type: () => GraphQLJSONObject }) user: object)
```

There's indeed some repetition, but that's because some type information is lost after Typescript is transpiled.